# How to properly change Java Runtime on Dokku app container?

Tags: java, java-11, ktor, dokku

I'm running a Ktor backend app inside of a Dokku container on a server. It seems that by default Java8 is used. How can I properly change Java Runtime on dokku container to be Java 11?

I'm not sure if I should enter the dokku app container and update the Java, or is there some configuration available that I can use either on the dokku or my Ktor project side, or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If deploying via the official heroku buildpack for java, you can specify a `java.runtime.version` in your `system.properties` as documented [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version).

example:

```
java.runtime.version=11
```